# VAIO VPC-SA with i915 driver display blink/noise

Tags: linux, sony-vaio, laptop-display

I have a VAIO VPC-SA laptop, with an Ubuntu 11.4 installed.
The problem lies in the strange screen blinking/noise which is mostly
noticeable in grey gradients and causes eyes fatigue and pain after
prolonged use.

This problem does not occur with the VESA driver and Windows, but it's
reproduced in Fedora Core and Ubuntu 10.08/11.08 at X-window and
cosole (with i915 module). It is clear that the problem is in the
driver, but I can't determine the source of noise, it may be because
of the backlight, or the display-panel.

I captured it and it [looks like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_profilepage&v=C3LcYLrFwHU).

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch called [[Intel-gfx] [PATCH] drm/i915: disable temporal dithering on the internal panel](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/intel-gfx/2011-October/012595.html).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. More specifically, where to find and how to apply the patch. Did the patch solve your problem? Consider putting an accept mark on your post for reputation.